# Custom Domain Redirect API

Tags: api, custom, redirect, domain

We are testing my domain change in sandbox and have a query

- Old domain: mytest-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
- New Domain: mytest-Dell-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/

The redirection is working fine from UI. My Q is if an external system (middleware or direct) hits API and uses absolute URL eg mytest-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/v50/xxxx, will the inbound request be automatically treated as mytest-Dell-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/v50/xxxx ?